# MFMailComposeViewController slow to render emails with attachments on iOS9

Tags: xcode, ios9, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

Opening a MFMailComposeViewController with attachment data takes a very long time to render the email on iOS9. The MFMailComposeViewController appears quickly, but its fields and contents (except Subject) are blank for a long time (e.g. 45s for an email with 10 attachments on an iPhone6). There appears to be no issue with the time it takes for the addAttachmentData method to run, the delay occurs at the view rendering stage.

Other people have experienced the same issue and it appears to be a bug in iOS9: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17124

My question is whether anyone has discovered a workaround allowing emails with attachments to render in an acceptable time? (Issue is still present in iOS 9.0.2)

Comment: This issue was resolved in iOS 9.2

Comment: In my case the issue still exists even in iOS 9.2.1. I do not have any attachments, so really no idea what takes so long.